# how to set items when soft keyboard is shown with using guideLine in constraint layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout, android-xml, constraintlayout-guideline

I am using `ConstraintLayout` in my application.

When soft keyboard is shown, I want to only button move above that And other items do not move up. I did this with using a `scrollView`.

Now I used `guideLine` to support all screen sizes, but after soft keyboard is shown, all items move to up again.

How should I use `guideLine` for this?

**Manifest :**

```
<activity
    android:name=".RegisterActivity"
    android:exported="false"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
<activity
```

**Xml :**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <ScrollView
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/button_register_sendVerification"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        >

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
                android:id="@+id/guideline_register_topParent"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.04" />

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
                android:id="@+id/guideline_register_bottomParent"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.96" />

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
                android:id="@+id/guideline_register_leftParent"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.08" />

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
                android:id="@+id/guideline_register_rightParent"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.92" />

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
                android:id="@+id/guideline_register_topMobileNumber"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.4"/>

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
                android:id="@+id/guideline_register_bottomMobileNumber"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.49"/>

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/textInputLayout_register_mobileNumber"
                style="@style/TextInputLayout.All"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/guideline_register_leftParent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/guideline_register_rightParent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline_register_topMobileNumber"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/guideline_register_bottomMobileNumber">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/textInputEditText_register_mobileNumber"
                    style="@style/TextInputEditText.All"
                    android:hint="@string/text_all_enterPhoneNumber"
                    android:inputType="phone"
                    android:maxLength="11"
                    android:textAlignment="center" />

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_register_sendVerification"
        style="@style/Button.all"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:text="@string/text_button_registerActivity_sendVerification"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, all [windowSoftInputModes](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#wsoft) will either shift the text view or hide the button.

If you want to use a windowSoftInputMode of `adjustResize`, you will have to accommodate a *ConstraintLayout* that will change it's height when the soft keyboard is shown and hidden. Since a percentage *Guideline* specifies its position as a percentage of the *ConstraintLayout's* height (not the screen height), the *Guideline's* position will shift as the layout's height changes.

In your case, the easiest way around this problem is to specify *Guideline* positions using an offset from the top of the *ConstraintLayout*. Since this offset will remain a constant distance from the top of the *ConstraintLayout* even as the *ConstraintLayout's* height changes, it will behave as you want.

You can also leave the percent *Guidelines* in and convert them programmatically to fixed *Guidelines*. That way you can get the 40% offset regardless of the device.

The following code will replace a percentage *Guideline* with a fixed offset *Guideline*.

```
private fun replaceGuideline(layout: ConstraintLayout, oldGuideline: Guideline) {
    require(layout.height > 0) { "ConstraintLayout must have gone through a layout pass." }
    Guideline(layout.context).apply {
        val lp = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(
            ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        )
        lp.orientation = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.HORIZONTAL
        layoutParams = lp
        id = oldGuideline.id
        setGuidelineBegin(oldGuideline.top)
        layout.removeView(oldGuideline)
        layout.addView(this)
    }
}
```

You could also specify a windowSoftInputMode of `adjustNothing` (which is strangely missing from the docs). You can then detect when the soft keyboard is opened and closed to adjust the position of the button, although detecting soft keyboard status is oddly tricky.

Comment: Thanks for help. As you said I used a specific guideLine and put it at bottom of scrollView and set layout_constraintGuide_begin instead of layout_constraintGuide_percent.  It works great now.